# What texture is used in this photo?

Tags: noise, vintage, texture

I want to know what texture is used in this photo. If you zoom in on the lighter parts of the photo, there seems to be some little tiny digital bubbles/circle type things (some type of grain or noise?) and they seem to not show up in the darker parts. Can anyone identify what is this or what it is called?

[image]

Close-up

[image]

Comment: The pattern itself looks like ["Truchet tiles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truchet_tiles)

Answer (score 21):

That's a 'halftone pattern'. Halftones are a method of creating color separations for offset printing printing presses. This image was probably scanned from an offset printed piece.

Offset printing presses don't really have the ability to print shading. Halftones use a series of dots of various sizes in a grid to give the illusion of gradation. In the standard CMYK process, the halftone screen for color is generally rotate at a slightly different angle: 0°, 15°, 45°, 75° being common and resulting in the "rosettes"  pattern you see.

Comment: There's a possibility it was done with a Ps plugin emulating the physical process [though Ps's own halftone plugin is nowhere near as 'real' as the OP's image.]

Comment: `...probably scanned from an offset printed piece`  ie: a magazine, etc.